# Spring Boot 1.2.1 still WARN "Error initializing SpringLiquibase" with liquibase 3.3.x

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

It appears there is still an issue with Spring Boot and libuibase 3.3.x.

```
    2015-02-16 11:07:34.117  WARN 7576 --- [           main] liquibase                                : Error initializing SpringLiquibase

java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getURL(ServletContextResource.java:156) ...
```

The same problem was noted already here on stackoverflow and the answer was that new version of Spring Boot 1.2.1 contains a patch for this issue but it seems still to be a problem with SB 1.2.1 and liquibase 3.3.0 (this is the version number of liquibase that SB 1.2.1 provides by default).

I'm just wondering if others who are using SB 1.2.1 and liquibase observe the same issue and maybe there is a solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I observe the same, my solution was to use a previous liquibase version, as it seems SB 1.2.1 still has problems with 3.3.1. 
This version did the trick:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```